# What are the files in the group_vars/all/ directory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I wonder what is the difference between a file placed under *group_vars/* and *group_vars/all/* directories? Aren't they serve for the same purpose of storing inventory group files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the vars in `group_vars/all.yml` they will be loaded for the `all` group (i.e. all machines except the implicit `localhost`)

If you want to separate your vars for the `all` group in different files, you can place all the different yaml files in the `group_vars/all/` directory. They will all be loaded for the `all` group in the same way.

You cannot mix the 2 possibilities: if you have a `all` directory in `group_vars`, this will take precedence over the `all.yml` file.

Although the `all` group was used in the above examples to stick to your question, the same is true for any group in your inventory.

Ref: [Organizing hosts and group vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables)